# SD card failed to initialize

Tags: sd-card, arduino-pro-micro

I have a Pro Micro board and I try to make it list my files as in the example of the Arduino IDE. 
The pins I use are the following:

```
board    micro sd module
   D4  ---> CS
   D15 ---> SCK
   D14 ---> MISO
   D16 ---> MOSI
   GND ---> GND
   VCC ---> VCC
```

On the serial monitor I get "initiallization failed".

What is wrong with my setup?

This is the code running:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

File root;

void setup() {
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }

  Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");

  if (!SD.begin(4)) {
    Serial.println("initialization failed!");
    while (1);
  }
  Serial.println("initialization done.");

  root = SD.open("/");

  printDirectory(root, 0);

  Serial.println("done!");
}

void loop() {
  // nothing happens after setup finishes.
}

void printDirectory(File dir, int numTabs) {
  while (true) {

    File entry =  dir.openNextFile();
    if (! entry) {
      // no more files
      break;
    }
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < numTabs; i++) {
      Serial.print('\t');
    }
    Serial.print(entry.name());
    if (entry.isDirectory()) {
      Serial.println("/");
      printDirectory(entry, numTabs + 1);
    } else {
      // files have sizes, directories do not
      Serial.print("\t\t");
      Serial.println(entry.size(), DEC);
    }
    entry.close();
  }
}
```

And this is my wiring:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: maybe your program consists of only these two commands ..... `Serial.begin(9600);  Serial.println("initiallization failed");`  ..... that would give you the observed output

Comment: did you insert the card?

Comment: what are the voltages of board and SD module?

Comment: @jsotola I study computer science man, this is not one of my possible mistakes. But thank you for your comment

Comment: @Juraj Yes I inserted the card. How can I see the voltages?

Comment: in specification. pro micro's are 5 V or 3.3V. SD card modules are with voltage conversion to 5 V or only a holder for SD card with 3.3V native voltage

Comment: So the voltages are ok? I connect it to my pc via usb. How can I look further to this? I am sure it should have worked by now.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers I did, any guesses?

Comment: connection to USB doesn't say anything about voltages. add links to where you bought them, if you don't know the specs

Comment: I bought both the board and the module a long time ago from Ebay. The module is from Catalex and says v1.0. My sd card is a standard one (Kingston 4gb) and the module is probably the cheapest pro micro on ebay.

Comment: Catalex SD module is 5 V. On pro micro you could measure a voltage of an OUTPUT HIGH pin

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: is the SD card formatted to FAT or FAT32?

Comment: I am not sure. Could this be the problem?

Comment: that would be definitely the problem. put the card in a computer and check it

Comment: it was ntfs I am sure, I am formating it to FAT now. But this should be a problem at software level, doesn't it? Due to my sketch it seems that it fails to init

Comment: do you have a voltmeter/multimeter to measure voltage of vcc or a pin?

Comment: No, not yet. I have ordered a multimeter but it has not arrived yet

Comment: is something written on the bottom side of the pro micro?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85130/discussion-between-george-sp-and-juraj).

Comment: I only would think of inserting the SD card, using a FAT (not NTFS) formatted card, and optionally try another SD card (got problems myself depending on the SD Card). Also I would advice buying a (around 5$) logic analyzer from Ebay, than you can relatively easy find out what's going over the jumper wires.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers, read the chat finale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SD library works only with FAT and FAT32 format. SD.begin() reads the 'disc volumes' and opens the root folder. If the card is not formatted or formatted with other file system standard, begin() fails.

EDIT: and the pin headers must be soldered

[image]

Comment: Yea, I got it. I just formated it to FAT32 and it didnt work either. What else could it be?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my setup code for my SD card for a little circuit where I was writing temperature data to the card.

```
const int SD_CS = 10;
   const long SLEEP_TIME = 60000;  // write to card every minute
   long multiplier = 0;

   LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x3F, 20, 4);

   void setup() {

     lcd.begin();
     lcd.setCursor(2,0);
     lcd.print("Hello, LCD!");  

     if (SD.begin(SD_CS)) { // init SD 
       lcd.setCursor(2,2);
       lcd.print("SD card init");
     }

 }
```

I set the CS pin to D10.
Try switching it to another pin like this and see if you get a different result.  I believe I had a challenge when I used pin 4 but can't quite remember.

**Note**: And of course remember to move your CS wire to pin D10 or whichever one you use.

Comment: the problem is revealed in chat

Comment: @Juraj Headers not soldered! Yipes! I asked a relevant question about this long ago -- https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/249140/how-can-i-make-connection-on-pcb-circuit-board-holes-without-solder-for-proto 
Great catch!