# digitalWrite on Trace SWO pin

Tags: pins, digitalwrite

I'm using STM32(generic board) and I want to control bi-color LED(common anode). STM32 pin layout and scheme is below, so please see it.
Now, in theory scheme Works, but in practice it Works halfway. Red LED is connected with `PB8` pin and green LED is connected with `PB3` pin.
Code is simple so I think that problem is not in the code. Red LED Works, but green doesn't work. If I connect green cathode with GND manually, then it Works, otherwise(with STM32) it doesn't.
Later I found that pin `PB3` has `Trace SWO` mark(see pin layout below). I'm not completly sure what `Trace SWO` means, just found that it some kind of debugigng protocol(I guess) but I can't find info can it be used for `digitalWrite` purposes. Is there any way to habilitate `PB3` pin for `digitalWrite`? All other pins are in use.

Code:

```
// DOWN   
digitalWrite(PB3, HIGH);
digitalWrite(PB8, LOW);
delay(750); 

// UP
digitalWrite(PB8, HIGH);
digitalWrite(PB3, LOW);
delay(750);
```

[STM32 pin layout](https://www.bing.com/images/search?view=detailV2&id=69E683278A7EF9AC68EF7C923FB9A5FF20165E5A&thid=OIP.pPrFsHEEJy5Szpz6-Q6mpwHaFM&exph=759&expw=1082&q=stm32+pin+layout&selectedindex=0&ajaxhist=0&vt=0&eim=1,2,6)

[image]

**R4 doesn't exist, it's mistake in scheme**

Comment: did you solder the headers?

Comment: Don't understand you?

Comment: usually the Blue Pill is sold without pin headers soldered

Comment: @Juraj really? I didn't know that. Thanks for info! ‍♂️

Comment: how can you don't know that? did you get it with pin headers soldered or without pin headers? https://cdn.instructables.com/F46/4FA4/JM8A987M/F464FA4JM8A987M.LARGE.jpg

Comment: Are you troll or? Of course I soldered pins. STM32 is on breadboard. How could I use STM32 without headers and breadboard?! Btw. I fixed the problem. Just deleted line in boards.txt file.

Comment: I didn't ask if you SOLDERED the headers.  I asked if YOU soldered the headers. :-) If I solder the headers then I test the pins and sometimes I must fix the soldering. I always first ask basic things, because many times they are the problem.

Comment: like here https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/57370/sd-card-failed-to-initialize/57387#57387